# Need help escaping html special character in regex and php

Tags: php, regex, escaping, character

I have three line of code that calculate the length of characters put between < and > in a string submitted by a user.

```
$Msg = '<Part1>Hello!<Part2>Hello again!<Part3>';
preg_match_all('/<([^>]*)>/', $Msg, $msglenght);
$msglenght = mb_strlen(join($msglenght[1]), 'UTF-8');
echo $msglenght;
```

The lines work fine, but as I'm putting them in a program that has user submitted special characters converted, I need to alter the regex line to:

```
preg_match_all('/&#60;([^&#62;]*)&#62;/', $Msg, $msglenght);
```

But now, if a user uses the semicolon (;) in a submitted string, the program doesn't calcolate the number of characters correctly. I don't know practically anything about regex, how the line should be changed to having the semicolon properly escaped?

Comment: You may use `'/&#60;(.*?)&#62;/s'`. You may even unroll it as `'/&#60;([^&]*(?:&(?!#62;)[^&]*)*)&#62;/'`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly fine :)